# Is there any way to enable pagination on teams messaging extension search queries?

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using MS teams search based messaging extension, is there any way to capture scroll event in bot.

So, when the user queries a keyword,with counter=1, response will have top 10 matching results.
After scrolling down, i want to hit another query for the same keyword with counter=2, to return next 10 matching results.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, or any other way to paginate large result sets within the waterfall dialog format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using queryOption array you can enable pagination.

Pagination parameters:

skip: Skip count for this query

count: Number of elements to return.

Please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet) for more info.

Comment: How do we actually enable paging? I always get skip = 0, there must be some way to notify the front end that there are additional items to return?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just realized you were asking about a messaging extension but I think this may still be applicable so leaving it here.

I was able to implement a solution that doesn't depend on TeamsActivityHandler (which I am not using). In my case I created a separate dialog (paginateDialog) which has a data array and current page value in the options for the begin dialog call. The data array contains card definitions which I display as a carousel. My code below is specific to that case, so if you are sending a different type of message you may need to modify something.

```js
var paginate = require('array-paginate');

    async displayItems (step) {

        // Display the first page
        var items = paginate(step._info.options.lineData, step._info.options.currentPage, PAGE_SIZE);
        await step.context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.carousel(items.docs));

        // If there are more items, prompt to continue and increment
        if (items.hasNextPage == true) {
            return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
                prompt: `I can only show you ${PAGE_SIZE} items at a time. Please select Next to continue or Done to return to the main dialog.`,
                choices: [
                    {value: `Next ${PAGE_SIZE}`},
                    {value: 'Done'}
                ]
            });
        } else {
            return await step.next();
        }
    }

    async loopStep (step) {
        if (step.result && step.result.value == `Next ${PAGE_SIZE}`) {
            step._info.options.currentPage++;
            return await step.replaceDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, step._info.options);
        } else {
            return await step.endDialog();
        }
    }
```

Note that this is probably not very efficient, especially if you have a very large array, as I am recreating the pagination from the full array each time. This allows you to traverse the pages forwards and backwards if you need to, though. My function only goes forward, but you could create Forward and Back buttons which can be displayed dynamically based on hasNextPage and hasPreviousPage values returned by `array-paginate` module and then increment/decrement current page as applicable.

One other note, this is called via `return await step.beginDialog('PAGINATE_DIALOG', options);` This means when you end that dialog, you will return to the called at the NEXT step, regardless of where in the step you call the dialog (just like any other dialog call). So know if you have any prompts or anything else after `beginDialog`, you'll need to account for those in your pagniateDialog steps before returning to the previous dialog.